# 'TFOptimizer' object has no attribute 'learning_rate'

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am getting following error when I used `opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)` In `model.compile`.

model.compile(opt, sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[iou_score],)

```
AttributeError: 'TFOptimizer' object has no attribute 'learning_rate'
```

When I used "Adam" only, It works but I cannot set learning rate with second option.

```
model.compile("Adam", sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[iou_score],)
```

How can I set particular Learning rate.

Comment: There is no `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)` in your shown code; please edit & update accordingly

Comment: The key for `tf.keras.optimizer.Adam` is `adam`, not `Adam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you implemented your compiling stage, but I guess the following code will work.

```
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[iou_score])
```